# Using virtualenv within pythonbrew | Installing dependencies

Tags: python, python-2.7, virtualenv, pip, pythonbrew

from this question:

[Manage python version in different virtualenv with pythonbrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14802536/manage-python-version-in-different-virtualenv-with-pythonbrew)

I followed the instructions of the answer and typed in:

```
pythonbrew venv create project1
```

After doing this, virtualenv was installed and this new venv was installed here:

user/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.6/project1

What I would like to know is how I would be able to install dependencies within this virtualenv using pip?

Based on my current knowledge, I would assume that running the command to install dependencies from the generic terminal spot (user/) will make the dependencies get installed in the main pythonbrew install and not the virtual environment.

I am building multiple web projects using different python tools (but the same/latest python 2.7 version), so I would like to keep each project(and their different dependencies) separate.

Comment: Forget pythonbrew (even the author deems it "deprecated".) Just use plain ``virtualenv`` to create local (to current directory) virtual Python environments. And put your required modules in ``requirements.txt`` and run ``pip -r requirements.txt``.

Comment: There are some major differences between pythonbrew and virtualenv which deem it necessary for me to use pythonbrew, otherwise I would use virtualenv exclusively.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use that project's `pip` to install desired module.

In your case, for example:

```
user/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.6/project1/bin/pip install mpipe
```

Dump the newly installed module's version:

```
user/.pythonbrew/venvs/Python-2.7.6/project1/bin/python -c 'import mpipe; print(mpipe.__version__)'
```

Output is:

```
1.0.7
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe pythonbrew has some baked in commands (as I discovered while trying to find the document in my own answer) for venv.

Answer (score 1):

I think I have found the ideal solution here:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pythonbrew/

By running this:

```
pythonbrew venv use proj
```

And then running:

```
pip install -U django==x.x.x
```

It will install a dependency like django into the virtual environment, even if you have other versions of it.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in thinking that running `pip` in the terminal will update the entire system while running it in particular environment will only update that particular virtual environment.